# jquery and bootstrap in application customizer and multiple webparts

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, bootstrap-5, web-parts, spfx

Is a personal choice to use bootstrap for customization. So, I am planning to use jQuery and Bootstrap in application customizer and multiple web parts. What is the best approach for this? I am trying to avoid loading libraries multiple times.

Comment: Please see [ask]. A better title might be "How can I avoid loading duplicate libraries in Web Parts?" The question really has nothing to do with Bootstrap or jQuery.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194213/would-multiple-spfx-webparts-on-page-load-duplicate-dependencies

You want them to be referenced externally. Link Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript files:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note: Bootstrap v5 is not using jQuery, it uses just vanilla JavaScript. More info: https://blog.logrocket.com/bootstrap-adoption-guide/

Let me know if this helps.